# Can I retrieve the Access Token from Spring Security Oauth?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

context: I'm trying to play with google playlists, just list them now

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&maxResults=25&mine=true&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

So I've got google login set up with Spring Boot 2.1.6, as follows (it works)

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=...
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=...
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.token-uri=https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.authorization-uri=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.user-info-uri=https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.jwk-set-uri=https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.issuer-uri=https://accounts.google.com
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=profile,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
```

according to [google google docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) I should get an access/authorization token back during the requests spring makes. How can I retrieve this token so I can make further calls to API's such as youtube?

Comment: Are you using Spring Security OAuth or Spring Security 5?

Comment: @NatFar spring security 5

Comment: @xenoterracide - did you already found any solution?

Comment: @ManojShevate yes, I asked upstream, Joe Grandja never posted his answer back here, instead chastizing me for not asking here first... which I had and had posted the link to. Anyways... I added the answer here. I can't remember if I tried it.

Comment: @ManojShevate Please see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7088#issuecomment-511820737

Answer (score 8):

from @jgrandja https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7088#issuecomment-511820737

> No, it doesn't get wiped out. You can retrieve the `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` via the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` or `OAuth2AuthorizedClientService`. The `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` contains the `OAuth2AccessToken` and optional `OAuth2RefreshToken`.
> See the [ref doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2Client-authorized-repo-service) for further info.

> Also, a more convenient way of obtaining the `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` is via [@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2Client-registered-authorized-client).

> I encourage you to read the ref doc as there is quite a bit of info there that will likely answer your questions.

> - [OAuth 2.0 Client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2client)
> - [OAuth 2.0 Login](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login)

Answer (score 1):

If Spring Security is configured for an OAuth 2.0 Login, the `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter` uses [`HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository.java) (by default) to store the authenticated user in the session. Although the `Authentication` object (`OAuth2AuthenticationToken`) unfortunately does not have the raw token, you should be able to extract it from the client that's been saved in the session:

```
String attributeName = HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository.class.getName()
                           +  ".AUTHORIZED_CLIENTS";

Map<String, OAuth2AuthorizedClient> authorizedClients = request.getSession()
                                                      .getAttribute(attributeName);

OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = authorizedClients.get("google");

String token = client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
```

Although this should work, it is very brittle. Hopefully there's another solution that doesn't involve swapping in custom implementations into the security framework.

Comment: are you sure about that location in the session? maybe I'm not using Spring Security 5 though I don't see any jars on the classpath that aren't versioned 5.x.

```
    implementation(enforcedPlatform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.1.6.RELEASE"))
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
    implementation(kotlin("reflect"))
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client")
```